# Is old hard drive dead?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure, bsod, chkdsk

So a couple of days ago my 3 year old laptop with win7 was acting up (programs didn't respond etc.) so I've decided to run a chkdsk, however this turned out to be a bad idea since it stalled at one file on stage 4/5 for about 24 hours, I got a BSOD with bad_system_config_info error, and whenever I now boot Windows, after a couple of minutes it becomes completely non responsive and I have to forcefully shut it down. I've booted a portable version of Ubuntu and ran gsmartcontrol, and got the following results for the hard drive:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus 5400.6
Device Model:     ST9500325AS
Serial Number:    S2WFPRB7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 04b0cae93
Firmware Version: 0005HPM1
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 19 19:42:26 2015 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 135) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   070   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       81234683
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0002   099   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0033   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       2202
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   091   091   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       201
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       290912486
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       10198
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0033   098   098   020    Pre-fail  Always       -       2115
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       34578
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295042219
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   046   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 25/34)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       68
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       27004
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 10 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   048   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       81234683
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   091   091   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       201
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1846
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       3

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 27473 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 27473 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10196 hours (424 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:18.260  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:15.784  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:13.274  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:10.854  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.432  READ DMA EXT

Error 27472 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10196 hours (424 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:15.784  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:13.274  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:10.854  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.432  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.358  READ DMA EXT

Error 27471 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10196 hours (424 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:10.854  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.432  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.358  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.288  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.225  READ DMA EXT

Error 27470 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10196 hours (424 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.432  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.358  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.288  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.225  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 ff ff ff ef 00      00:07:08.166  READ DMA EXT

Error 27469 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10196 hours (424 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 71 04 9d 00 32 e0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      21:58:55.850  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      21:58:55.746  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      21:58:55.642  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      21:58:55.539  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 e0 00      21:58:55.435  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     10198         547053969
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     10197         547053969
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     10197         547053969

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I've no idea what any of this means since I'm not exactly familiar with Linux, so basically what I'm asking is: is the drive dead, or can it be fixed? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Drive's no good. Pull as much data off the drive as possible and replace it.

Comment: it is at least on its way out, 200 bad sectors, plus many more again.. The only way it isnt dead is if the power going to it is all screwed up causing it to have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the HDD has 201 Reallocated Sector Count:

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   091   091   036    Pre-fail  Always       -   201
```

This is usually a sign of imminent failure. Even if it hasn't failed at the moment already, it will fail soon in the future. Try to get as much data as you can from it before it's too late.

Comment: `ATA Error Count: 27473 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)` - emphasizes this even more.

Answer (score 1):

Drive is not completely dead, but starting to. You should be able to read data off your old HD but try to prevent writing to it. If you can get a USB-to-SATA bridge adapter and then using another computer start pulling the data off.

Here is a link to [Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/SATA-Adapter-Cable-Power-Cord/dp/B001OOT804/ref=sr_1_3/189-0127299-6154246?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1440011388&sr=1-3&keywords=cable%20usb%20sata) showing the adapter I'm talking about.

Good luck.